# What are these connectors called (home applicances)?

Tags: connector, electrical

I see these connectors inside a microwave oven and other home appliances. They are installed on the ends of wires and have round edges, while the middle section is flat. What are they called and do splitters exist that split one such connection into two? Thanks[image]

Comment: A trade name is "Faston"

Answer (score 2):

Spade connectors. Often used in cars too.

Comment: Many times a spade connector is attached with a screw. I have seen spade terminals and fork terminals used interchangeably to refer to the same thing. It is more common to refer to these as FASTON or quick-connect. See https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-spade-connectors/391

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do make splitters. They look like this sometimes:[image: splitter]

Answer (score 0):

You will often find these on the electronics site referred to as angled or [flag quick connects.](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-quick-connects-quick-disconnect-connectors/392?k=flag%20spade)
[image]

You will find splitters and male to females often listed as [terminal adapters](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-adapters/405?k=male%20to%20femal%20quick%20connect).

[image] [image] [image]